# Matlab: Saving plot on cluster does not work

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, matlab-figure

I'm using Matlab on a cluster and I have problems with plotting. I have to run Matlab in nodisplay mode, so OpenGL is not available. Unfortunately, the zrenderer is no more available in Matlab. So what remains is the painters. This seems to work for the plot command of Matlab.

Now, for saving the figure I'm using export_fig. When I want to use the painters option of export_fig, I have to use ghostscript which is not available on the cluster.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why is OpenGL not available? It should still be able to use the software implementation. Right? Also in general, it's a bad idea to be doing any soft of graphics on the cluster nodes. It is far better to shuttle data around and then do your plotting elsewhere.